# Search in the control WebBrowser

Tags: browser

as in the WebBrowser control are to find all occurrences of a keyword, highlight them and go to the first occurrence ?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412648/how-to-highlight-a-specific-word-in-webbrowser-control-c

Answer (score 0):

IE's webbrowser controls supports many edit features, you can [either change the HTML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753624(VS.85).aspx) or [add segments to the highlight render service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753630(VS.85).aspx#Manipulating_Markup).